# How to allow duplicate SKU in Magento

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I have a customer who retails third party batteries, and some batteries can replace several OEM models.

For instance, 3rd party SKU 12345 may replace Toshiba N23 and HP 53214, thus my customer would like to create two products with the same SKU in front end (they are essentially the same product). However, Magento by default does not allow duplicated SKU.

My current solution is to set SKU to not required from the backend, and add another attribute called Model that allows duplicated values, and display the Model in front end.

Is there a better way to do this? Or is it possible to allow duplicated SKU?

Tian Bo
[Noble Technologies](http://www.noble.sg/)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds to me like you've found a good solution. I'm not so sure you should try to have duplicate values for SKU for two reasons.

First the whole point of SKU is that it is a unique identifier. That's its only reason for existing. If you're going to  have duplicate values, then it's not a unique identifier; it's just another attribute. But of course Magento still needs a unique identifier to work, which means that this is an extra field, which takes us exactly where you are now.

That said we come to my second point which is this... I'm not exactly a Magento guru, but I've built my share of e-commerce sites and one thing I've learned is that they depend on certain unbreakable rules to work properly. One  of them is that unique identifiers are *unique*, both on the database and application level. As such, a large part of the website depends on this to function correctly. Which I'm pretty sure goes for Magento too.

So trying to change such a basic premise in something so complicated will only lead to horrors and a slow descent into madness.

Comment: SKU = Stock Keeping Unit, a unique ID for stock counting purposes. So, the way we always handled this is to have a base SKU with a counter tacked to the end. You then have a Custom Attribute that contains the manufacturer part number to aid you in inventory count. Real businesses do inventory counts and the SKU is the final say-so on what the item is in your system.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a good solution that I extended a bit further, however what I did with multiple store was to create a visible attribute ITEM_SKU (Item SKU) - make it visible and searchable and then concatenate   the store_id to Magneto SKU to make it unique.
So  SKU becomes (Store_id "-" SKU).

Answer (score 1):

It surprises me how often people are willing to break who-knows-what parts of Magento, just to get a specific piece working how they expect.

The proper way to allow for duplicate skus is NOT to (unless you'd like to re-write large parts of the framework). You CAN, however, add a custom attribute to products that shares all the same settings as "sku" minus the setting that requires values to be unique.

Changing product pages, emails, etc to show this value instead will require a little extra work but will save you headaches later.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create 1 product (SKU 12345) and list this product in multiple categories. So your multiple categories will be Toshiba and HP. The same product (SKU 12345) will be listed in Toshiba and HP.